# Database user session gets created after session kill

Tags: sql, oracle, session, database-administration

After killing session by using `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION`, I tried to drop the user, but it says the user is connected.

So when I again killed the session and tried to drop the user, I observed that each time I kill a session, immediately another session is getting created.

Example :

I run the query "Drop user cascade" : it says user connected cannot drop

I run the query:

```sql
SELECT 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||s.sid||','|| s.serial#||''';'  
  FROM v$session s, v$process p 
 WHERE lower(s.username) = 'username'
  AND p.addr(+) = s.paddr and status='INACTIVE';
```

I get a query to kill sessions, now I kill all the sessions and run the drop user command again, it says user connected.

Checking for sessions again on the user shows a single inactive session which is getting created each time.

Comment: MySQL or Oralce? [Edit] the question and remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: This is not MySQL so I removed the tag.

Comment: Yes, its oracle db.

Comment: Is it really a new session being created, or an old session that survives the kill? What status does it have? ([This](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions#kill_session) might be useful).

Comment: Is it a new session or the same old session? If the SID and SERIAL# are the same, then the session was never really killed, even though the kill command "succeeded". In that case, Oracle might be busy rolling back a transaction. If there is a large transaction, it must be rolled back and there's no way to stop it from happening. You can check `select used_urec, gv$transaction.* from gv$transaction` to see how many UNDO records need to be applied. Run that query repeatedly and the number should decrease, and you can use that to estimate when the rollback will finish.

Comment: Handy [undo tracker](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/undo_tracker.shtml) (SQL\*Plus script)

Comment: @JonHeller, No, They are not the same sesions, i mean they are not the same SID and SERIAL# each time, its a seperate session.

Comment: @AchuthaK Try locking the user before you kill the sessions, to ensure that no more sessions can connect. Run `alter user username account lock`.

Comment: @AlexPoole It was a new session, and the issue is resolved now after i locked the user and dropped, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping a user for an application that quickly reconnects may require a few steps:

1. Prevent the user from reconnecting with `alter user username account lock`
2. Kill the user's sessions with `alter system kill session ...`
3. Wait for any long-running transactions to rollback. Monitor the rollback progress by repeatedly running `select used_urec, gv$transaction.* from gv$transaction`
4. Drop the user with `drop user username`